# Is it impossible to create a Functor instance of this data type?

Tags: haskell, types, functor, fractions

I'm trying to make this data type an instance of `Functor`:

```
data Fraction = Frac Integer Integer deriving Show
```

But, defining it like this will not work:

```
instance Functor Fraction where
  pure = Frac 1 1
  fmap f (Frac a b) = Frac (f a) (f b)
```

I *want* this functionality, and I would prefer the data to be an instance of Functor. But, does that violate some laws since the parameters of `Fraction` are always two `Integers`?

I could always just write `fmap` on it's own and avoid the `Functor` declaration, but I'm trying to get more familiar with the language, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you cannot define a functor without having a type variable to "leave out" for the declaration (Or more formally: a functor instance must be defined for something of kind `* -> *`). The signature of `fmap` is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so in order to satisfy that contract, it must be possible to pick any types `a` and `b` for the function.

You can of course just redefine `Fraction` to be this:

```
data Fraction a = Frac a a deriving Show
```

... or you could use the existing data type for fractions/rational numbers in [Data.Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Ratio.html), which doesn't form a functor because nobody has deemed it useful to have such an instance (what would you use it for, anyways?), but at least you'd be using a well-established and existing data structure then.

Comment: I'm building up a small library for a sort of exercise. `fmap` may not actually even be useful at all... I guess that's a good point.

But, in any case, thank you for the clarification! That helps me out a bunch.

Comment: The only use for `fmap` that I see is that it could be used for dividing both the numerator and denominator by some common value, but that's easy enough to do with e.g. pattern matching. Also, I think the largest sign that something is amiss is that there's no sensible way of implementing `pure` for `Fraction`, even if it was constrained to using only `Integer`. Why is the number `1/1` special? Why not `0/12` or `42/1`? But you might be interested in the `Monoid` type class, and the various classes in the [`algebra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/algebra) package.

Comment: (For the algebra package, you might have to click on a previous version to read the documentation, because the latest version is glitched somehow and lacks documentation)

Comment: A monoid type class is perfect, actually. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @dflemstr, 1 and 0 are special numbers, so their "smallest" representations (`1/1` and `0/1`) are also special. But your point that classes from `algebra` are more appropriate still stands.

Comment: @dbaupp, `pi`, `e`, `i` are also special numbers. But you are right in that `0` is the identity for addition and `1` is the identity for multiplication. That has nothing to do with functors, though.

Comment: I think `fmap` isn't merely unuseful for `Ratio`, but actually harmful: it would allow the user to break the invariant otherwise preserved by module boundaries that fractions are in reduced form.